# Automatic "regular" chords (not arpeggios) in FL Studio

Tags: chords, software, daw

Is it possible to configure an instrument in FL Studio to play a chord (e.g., a major triad, a dominant seventh, etc.) when a single note is played (using the single note as the root)? For reference, this option is available in LMMS on the FUNC tab (where arpeggios can also be configured).

[image: The FUNC tab in LMMS.]

In FL Studio, it's possible to set up an automatic arpeggio (in the appropriately-named "Arpeggiator" panel on the FUNC tab), but it doesn't seem possible to produce non-arpeggiated chords.

[image: The FUNC tab in FL Studio.]

FL Studio does have a chord tool in the piano roll editor, but I'm looking for functionality analogous to that of LMMS (i.e., automatic, real-time construction of chords in response to MIDI or keyboard input of single notes). I've done quite a bit of googling and looked at the documentation for FL Studio but haven't found a solution; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

FL Studio appears to support MIDI VST plugins - that's plugins that alter MIDI data, rather than audio.

Tobybear had a chorder in his MIDIBag package (apparently still available at http://www.tobybear.de/files.html, though his main site is offline now), and http://hgsounds.com/news/vst-plugins/arp/setting-up-midi-vst-plugins-in-fl-studio/ describes how you can set up MIDI VSTs in FL, though it warns that it may not be possible to route them to the internal synths, so you may need to choose another VST synth to route the MIDI plugin to.

http://www.sadglad.com/midi_plugins.html has a longer list of MIDI plugins.
http://www.mucoder.net/en/tonespace/ also claims to be able to generate MIDI.